# Htaccess redirecting in the wrong way

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using a simple HTAccess redirect rule to redirect :-

```
http://localhost/sell_script/s.php?value=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/sell_script/s/1
```

When I directly load `http://localhost/sell_script/s.php?value=1`, it works fine. But when I load `http://localhost/sell_script/s/1` it again redirects me to `http://localhost/sell_script/s.php?value=1`.

What might be the problem here?

My htaccess :-

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^s/(.*) sell_script/s.php?value=$1 [R]
```

Comment: but this rule describes exactly the second behaviour. Where is the rule for the first behaviour?

Comment: I;m not good at rewrites.i followed a tutorial and landed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this simple re-write for you.

```
#ErrorDocument 404 /
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^s/(.+)$ s.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This would redirect `s.php?id=1` to `s/1`.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear from what you have above, the redirect is *from*

```
http://localhost/sell_script/s/1
```

*to*

```
http://localhost/sell_script/s.php?value=1
```

Not the other way around.

If your `RewriteBase` is `/`, you should include the `sell_script` in your rule.

```
RewriteRule ^sell_script/s/(.*)$ /sell_script/s.php?value=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also note, I have added an `L` to make the rule an endpoint, and changed the rewrite to a `301` code which is more search-engine friendly, among other things.

Comment: Your rule throws a 500 Internal Server Error for both `http://localhost/sell_script/s.php?value=1` and `http://localhost/sell_script/s/1`

Comment: I had L and R backwards in the rule delimeters. Try now.

Comment: Loading `localhost/sell_script/s/1` redirects to me :- `http://localhost/s.php?value=1` which doesn't exists.

Comment: K use the first one then

Comment: Same thing happens. 
"
 
Loading localhost/sell_script/s/1 redirects to me :- http://localhost/s.php?value=1 which doesn't exists. "

Comment: That is not technically possible based on what is left in the answer above. Clear your local and server caches and check your other rules.

Comment: I'll upload it online and provide a link to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93905/discussion-between-user5388577-and-jameson).